# Testing Android In App Billing real purchases

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing

What are the conditions to properly test real purchases, when i already have tested my app using test product like `android.test.purchased`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There are few steps that you need to pass, remembering, that some of them need some time to update on Google Play servers.

For this example, let's use `com.example.product` as our real product Id. Any time it shows up in this example change it to your own.

## **UPLOAD APK FILE**

> You **CAN'T** test REAL PURCHASES in DEBUG mode. You need to download an app from Beta, so Google know it's ok to make purchases in the app.

1. Check if you have BILLING permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
   ```
2. Change `android.test.purchased` to `com.example.product`,
3. Export *.apk file. It **MUST BE SIGNED**!
4. Publish APK in Beta,
5. You can now go to the next steps, but you'd need some time for your Beta to be ready for download.

## **ADD NEW PRODUCT**

> You **CAN'T** add new product until you have published a beta.
>
> <del>You **CAN'T** test subscriptions, only products.</del> Now you **CAN** also test subscriptions (they are renewed every 24h)

1. Go to products section in Google Play Developer Console,
2. Click `Add new product` button and define new product with `com.example.product` Id,
3. Wait **FEW HOURS** until it's published.

## **TESTERS**

> You **CAN'T** test purchases being signed-in on your device with a developer account. You **CAN'T** make purchases from yourself.

1. Create testing group on Google Groups, or Google Plus,
2. Add gmail accounts of your testers to that group,
3. Set your group as testers in `Google Play Developer Console > APP > BETA`
4. Copy testers emails in `Google Play Developer Console > SETTINGS > LICENSE TESTING` - this will make testing purchases enabled for their accounts.

## **TESTING**

> As a tester, you **WON'T** be charged

When testing from downloaded app Beta, you'll see a testing information on first IAP dialog.

You'll see both your product's name and price set in dev console.

You'll be testing with your real payment options. Don't be scared of seeing your credit card. As i mentioned before - you won't be charged.

When you successfully make a test purchase, you'll get a confirmation e-mail, which looks like a real purchase confirmation.

## **CLEANING TEST PURCHASES**

> To repeat the same purchases, you'll need to consume products, cancel purchases, or simply wait 2 weeks until testing purchases will expire.

To cancel purchases:

1. As a Developer, go to Google Wallet, choose purchases, and cancel them (remember to manage calceled purchases in your app),
2. As a Tester, go to app manager on your device, and clear Google Play cache. Despite of canceling on developer side, your device stores the purchase information locally.

Comment: hi i did as you told but getting error as: "The item you were attemptinh to purchase could not be found." @cyborg86pl

Comment: @virendrao check your item’s unique product (ITEM_SKU) which you are purchasing.

Comment: Cancelling the purchase and clearing Google Play cache do not cancel the product. You either wait 72 hours till then it's completely removed or you create new products to test with. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Very important: the alpha or beta tester needs to "opt-in" for testing for it to work on the device. Open the link to the play-store on the test-device-browser and "become a tester". It won't work otherwise.

Comment: I was charged for an in-app purchase on alpha channel.

Comment: @Yaroslav make sure you have your email in both BETA and LICENSE TESTING lists. (Testers, p. 3 and 4 in the answer)

Comment: @cyborg86pl thanks. Btw I got refund very quickly, so if anyone gets charged, no worries, just get in contact with google.

Comment: I was not being charged until yesterday, now i am being charged from today. No changes made from my side between yesterday and today. Where can i contact Google regarding this?? I posted my query on Google play help forum.

Comment: @cyborg86pl you seems to know really a lot about this, please could you have a look at my post and help me out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503251/how-should-i-exit-in-app-purchases-test-mode