# How to test the newly added inapp purchases?

Tags: android

I'm a little bit confused.

I have an application version A uploaded and published at Google Play. It does not have any inapp purchase feature.

Now I have made version B (B>A) of the same application adding some inapp purchase to it. I have also defined some tests purchase accounts as they instruct to do in the docs.

Now if I upload my version B , Google Play complains that I should disable my version A. But I want my version A be there because it works and people download it.

How to do?

Comment: i've been working on this for a while recently, and there's my Q&A on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215913/testing-android-in-app-billing-real-purchases?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @cyborg86p If I upload my app as beta can I then install it (the same apk) from my pc by using adb? Google only needs the apk to be there as beta or alpha? Or does it need anything else?

Comment: All the details are in my linked answer. You'll unfortynately will have to wait until a beta is ready for download. You CAN'T test real products in debug mode. Please note, that you also can't test purchases with your developer account. It's better if you read whole my answer, there is everything you need to know.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now that I have read it I have understood the strategy to follow. Should you wish, you could post an answer to this question so I can accept.