# Debug in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Is it possible to debug an app with in-app billing? You have to upload a signed apk to Google Play if you want to test out your in-app billing with your own product ids. I tried replacing Android's own keystore with a custom one that I used for signing but kept the password set to "android" and the alias to "androiddebugkey" but when I uploaded it to Google Play, it still recognized the signing as being a debug version. I presume that Google Play can tell if something is signed as a debug app by testing out the password and alias.

I would like to test out real purchases in Android Studio but this seems to be elusive.

Comment: This question is answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215913/testing-android-in-app-billing-real-purchases?answertab=active#tab-top) Try it and it will help you alot

Comment: I already read that. The answer seems to be "no" - you cannot debug in-app purchases.