# Need help after being charged for IAP despite another highly upvoted SO saying I won't be during testing

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, billing, beta

In this thread: [Testing Android In App Billing real purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215913/testing-android-in-app-billing-real-purchases)

The poster says that you will NOT be charged and to "not be afraid" to put your credit card info when testing IAP's in Beta/Alpha as you "WON'T BE CHARGED"... well, he's wrong... I was charged, how can I get this money back? I am the developer of the app but I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are charged means It was happend a REAL purchase.

Refund options:

1. Merchant End:
   The real purchases do always reflect in merchant page. If you have the access to the merchant page, you can CANCEL and refund the purchase you made.
2. User perspective:
   you can request a refund [https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2479637?hl=en-IN](http://refund)

   You will be recieving an E-mail to the account with which you have done purchase. There you can see the links to initiate refunds.

   Initiate refund with in 48 hrs of purchase, where the refund is accepted from play store directly. If it is more than 48 hrs you have contact authoritative people of the app to make a refund.

Regarding money charge: If you add a credit card to a play store account, initially some amount will be debited from the card. This charges are not for being purchasing any in app feature. If you are aware of this please ignore.

Make sure you have your account under LICENSE TESTING group to not being charged on test purchases.